# How can I run GDB without root permissions on a Mac?

Tags: mac, permissions, root, netbeans, gdb

When I start GDB from the command line I have no problems. But when I start debugging a program from NetBeans (C++), I get this message:

**"Type the name and password of a user in the "Developer Tools" group to allow Developer Tools Access to make changes."**

My user is already in the "Developer Tools" group, but this fact seems to be ignored.

With the root password it lets me debug, but I would not debug with the root account!

I checked the GDB executable and path, and they all grant executable permissions to everyone.

Any idea? Thank you!

Platform:
MacOS X 10.6.6 - 
NetBeans 6.9.1 - 
GCC 4.2 - 
GDB 6.3.50-20050815

Comment: "With the root password it lets me debug, but I would not debug with the root account!" And why is that? It has root permissions either way.

Comment: @Daniel: First of all, I may not have the root password. Then, if I run any program as user, generally the program itself should not have more rights than the user who launched it. E.g. I do not think a buggy gdb launched by a user could ever corrupt another user's files.

Comment: How did you add your user to that group? What is that group's actual name, `_developer`? Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837889/non-admin-developer-on-snow-leopard).

Comment: [Why do I need root privileges to run GDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5302972/995714), [Why is gdb requiring root permission to debug user programs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25586972/995714)